# Android: ListView with multiple choice and subitems enabled

Tags: android

I'm trying to get my contacts on a list view. Now I know that using `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` enables me to select multiple contacts, but it views names only without numbers.

On the other side, `simple_list_item_2` can be used to show both name and number, but supports selection of only one contact.

Is there any template that combine them both? If not, how could I build my customized list with both features?

EDIT: This is the code I'm using

```
CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(this,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
Cursor c = cl.loadInBackground();
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, // Use a template
                                                         // that displays a
                                                         // text view
                    c, // Give the cursor to the list adapter
                    new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME},
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1},0); 

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Here, the second parameter of SimpleCursorAdapter is `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` but it supports only dealing with `android.R.id.text1`. So I can use items only, not subitems.

But in the following code

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, // Use a template
                                                         // that displays a
                                                         // text view
                    c, // Give the cursor to the list adapter
                    new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},0);
```

I can give it both `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME` and `NUMBER` to be written in `android.R.id.text1` and `android.R.id.text2`, but can't use multiple choice feature.

Comment: Can you put some code you use? It will help a lot.

Comment: You should customized your layout according to your requirement.

Comment: Dipu, so there is no template for both of them. Can you ellaborate more how to customize my own layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dipu said, you should make your own customized layout.
To show name and contact, you need two text views, and one check box for checking.

You can start coding from this tutorial:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Add one more text view to country_info.xml will solve your problem.

**ADDED**

To use a custom list view layout, you have to implement your own adapter.

This tutorial (2. Custom ArrayAdapter example) will help you figure out how to do that.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Heejin is excellent, but it's not important to implement a custom ArrayAdaptor. What only I needed to do is to write a custom layout and send it to the `SimpleCursorAdaptor` constructor.

The custom layout represent the layout of each item in the list view. I need each row to contain a `CheckedTextView` and another small `TextView` as a subitem. So I've made a layout called row_view.xml with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:text="CheckedTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I've just used it in the constructor

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_view, // Use a template
                                                         // that displays a
                                                         // text view
                    c, // Give the cursor to the list adapter
                    new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                    new int[] { R.id.checkedTextView, R.id.textView},0); 

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the full code

```
public class MultipleContacts extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID
        ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
        ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.multiple_contacts);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // Get a cursor with all people

        CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(this,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");

        Cursor c = cl.loadInBackground();
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.row_view, // Use a template
                                                     // that displays a
                                                     // text view
                c, // Give the cursor to the list adapter
                new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                new int[] { R.id.checkedTextView, R.id.textView},0); 

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //what to do when an item is clicked
        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
        Toast.makeText(this, checkedTextView.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
```

Please note that I've two layouts, one for the list view itself(called `multiple_contacts`) and the provided layout here (called `row_view`) is the layout for each item in the list view. All what I need from `multiple_contacts` is to write `setContentView(R.layout.multiple_contacts);`